# Mistake in previous visa application but visa approved. In new visa application what to do?

Tags: visas, uk

I’m currently on a student dependant visa in the UK, and during my visa application, I entered my mother’s date of birth incorrectly. I noticed this after I got my visa, and thus didn’t upload a covering letter.

Now that I’m progressing for a new visa application, Skilled Worker, is this an issue if I upload the correct date of birth?

The correct date of birth is there on the passport and her UK Visa she received recently if that helps.

I’m worried my new application will be inconsistent with the previous application.

If anything I know I should be correcting it. Do I upload a cover letter with her passport as proof?

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the examples when a seemingly unimportant detail needs to be corrected. And it could happen with any other field as well. Since, the case officer doesn’t take care much, it could be easily overlooked. But every case officer is different, so you never know! Therefore, it is important to ensure consistency in your visa applications. Since you've noticed the error, it's advisable to correct it in your new application. You can upload a cover letter explaining the discrepancy and provide supporting documents, such as your mother's passport and her recent UK visa, to demonstrate the correct date of birth. This will help avoid any issues with inconsistency between your previous and current applications.